# CSS not working in localhost cakephp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I downloaded a website from server which is done with cakephp. When i open it in localhost only the contents are showing.There is no design.I thing it is due to some error in htaccess.

My localhost path is  "http://localhost/Dreamweaver/works/app/app/webroot" and content in htaccess file

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
IfModule
```

Please help me.

Comment: I see in your link post in this question duplicated `app` directory.  
Try to remove only one and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit root/.htacces file with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ $ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/ $ 1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

root/app/.htaccess with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ $ webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/ $ 1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and root/app/webroot/.htaccess with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Finally restart apache server

Comment: which server are you using XAMPP or WAMP ?

Comment: am using xampp server